# Stack Level Too Deep in multi_json adapter logic

Tags: ruby, ubuntu, rspec, sinatra

I have a rspec suite that runs perfectly on OS X, but fails on ubuntu for all specs that call a specific method.

The error I am seeing is:

`SystemStackError - stack level too deep:
    /home/ubuntu/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194@testset/gems/multi_json-1.5.0/lib/multi_json.rb:75`

As shown I have a dependancy on active_support, which requires multi_json. This line is requiring the adapter for `json_gem`, all of this seems internal to the request parsing. The actual error occurs in the request parsing of the endpoint, somewhere inside of sinatra. None of my code is ever hit (my debug statement never gets hit).

As for the method, it is hitting a running test endpoint with a POST containing a small, preset JSON string as the body.

Help greatly appreciated!

Comment: What was passed into the `new_adapter` logic in multi_json, something internal I presume. It's just what I got when I added some debug output into the gems code

Comment: Have you tried updating to the latest version of multi_json? It's a v1.6.1 now. You could also try installing the different backend adapters, like Oj, and see if that changes anything.